# How to start AnimatedContainer animation after page loads?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I'm trying to create a custom progress bar that I want to have animate from 0 to the assigned value every time the page loads.

Here is the stateful widget:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:new_platform/constants.dart';

class ProgressBarWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final max;
  final val;

  ProgressBarWidget(this.max, this.val);

  @override
  _ProgressBarWidgetState createState() => _ProgressBarWidgetState();
}

class _ProgressBarWidgetState extends State<ProgressBarWidget> {
    var height;
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    height = widget.val;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
      height = widget.val;

      Widget stack = Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(90.0),
      child: Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            //background
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Color(0xFFE8F0F0),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
            height: 5,
            width: 100,
          ),
          AnimatedContainer(
              foregroundDecoration:  BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                  gradient: COOL_PURPLE_BLUE_GRADIENT,
                  boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                          color: THEME_BLUE,
                          spreadRadius: -1,
                          offset: Offset(0, 0),
                          blurRadius: 5)
                  ]),
            duration: Duration(milliseconds:800 ),
            //foregroundS
            curve: Curves.decelerate,
            height: 7,
            width: height,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
    return stack;
  }
}
```

Is it possible to delay the animation of the AnimatedContainer or do I have to use something else to achieve the desired effect.

Im still new to flutter so any help is appreciated.

Comment: no, you cannot "delay" the animation of `AnimatedController`

Comment: @pskink I see, what would you suggest I use instead?

Comment: an [AnimatedBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedBuilder-class.html)? edit (sorry i meant `AnimatedContainer` in the prev comment)

Comment: @pskink I see, i'll give it a try, thanks!

Comment: sure, good luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To process animation using `AnimatedContainer` during screen is loading in Flutter, you can use a `Future.delayed` in `initState` (I delays for 3 seconds to understand but you can delay 0 second for example):

[image]

**DartPad :** https://dartpad.dev/d56165e07a3e58215206790248611b38?null_safety=true

**Code:**

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(App());

class App extends StatefulWidget {
  _AppState createState() => _AppState();
}

class _AppState extends State<App> {
  Color color = Colors.green;
  String text = 'Wait 3s in green';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // Rebuild the screen after 3s which will process the animation from green to blue
    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3)).then((value) => setState(() {
          color = Colors.blue;
          text = 'Become blue !';
        }));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: AnimatedContainer(
          duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
          color: color,
          child: Center(
            child: Text(
              '${text}',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40.0),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```